# Is it mandatory to import a bean to JasperSoftStudio's classpath if I want to access its attributes?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a bean like this:

```
class PersonBean {
    String name;
    String lastName;
}
```

I want to pass it to jasper as a parameter, and access the properties `name` and `lastName`. Is it mandatory to import `PersonBean` to jasper's classpath to achieve it?

This is how I intend access the properties: `$P{P_PERSON}.getName()`.

I've tried to use `java.lang.Object` as the parameter type, but then jasper tries to cast it, that causes an exception.

Comment: The class has to exist to be used.

Comment: Yes you need to put it in the classpath otherwise it will not compile since your class can not be found

Comment: Honestly the question is strange, I can not decide if its to broad you like to understand why java needs classes in classpath or unclear you are actually having problem to put them in class path?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the attributes( name and lastName) of PersonBean class in a map of String as a key and Object as value. Pass this map to the jasper report.
Like :

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
PersonBean person = new PersonBean();
map.put("NAME", person.getName());
map.put("LASTNAME", person.getLastName());
```

Pass this map to your jasper report at the time of compiling it.
Also create the parameters as NAME and LASTNAME in the jasper report. You can set the parameter type as String

Answer (score 0):

My question was missing an important part, I corrected it and here is the answer:

Depends!

If you compile the report inside JasperSoftStudio, yes, you'll need to import the bean.
If not, then it's not necessary, and that is my case, I compile the reports at runtime.

In short: You will need the class in the classpath for compiling and running (obviously), in my case, since I just design the reports in JasperSoftStudio, it's not necessary.